# Error to load scss to Vue3 TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function

Tags: javascript, sass, vuejs3, sass-loader, webpack-5

I try to load scss style file to the Vue3 project.

I use:

```
"@vue/cli": "^4.5.13",
"@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.13",
"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.11",
"sass": "^1.32.13",
"sass-loader": "^11.1.1",
"vue": "^3.0.11",
"vue-resource": "^1.3.4",
"webpack": "5.0.0"
```

and I have still the sale problem:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
      at Object.loader (/home/dev/src/my-app/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:25:24)
```

All is up to date and I have removed my node_modules and reinstaled them. Ihave removed also node-sass so I have only sass package.

Comment: I also tryed to downgrade sass-loader to verson 1O it doesn't work in this project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same mistake today

```
 "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.12.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.11",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.11",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.9.0",
    "sass": "^1.34.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "vue-loader-v16": "^16.0.0-beta.5.4"
  },
```

change from "sass-loader": "^12.0.0" to "sass-loader": "^10.1.1"

run:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

for me it solved

Comment: It worked also for my. Thanks